# Apex coding issue

Tags: class

My executive anonymous window is unable to synchronize with classes;For eg
In anonymous Window i wrote:

```
Public class Dog
{
Public string name;
public integer age;
public void bark()
{
System.debug('Hello how are you?');
}
}
```

And in class page I wrote:

```
Dog d1 = new Dog();
d1.name = 'Tiger';
d1.age = 14;
d1.bark();
System.debug('Name of dog is ' +d1.name);
system.debug('Age of my dog is ' +d1);
```

Still its saying in error "Variable does not exist: name".
when iam watching this code in course video , tutor is able to run it without any isssue then y cant I
Pls help me gys (I am new to coding n seriously dont know whats going on)

The issue is not with the code. Whenever that asterisk symbol is there it is not able to run (But it is running in course video which I am referring, even if there is asterisk symbol). When i save the file, asterisk symbol disappears & then the program runs properly.
But the asterisk symbol immediately appears when I do some changes in program.
[image: Here pls have a look]

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it looks like you created the Dog class, then either failed to save the contents, or there was a compilation error when you tried to save. Your code saved when I copied it verbatim. You may want to try deleting the class and trying again, or typing it instead of copy-pasting it (maybe there's a stray character in your file somewhere).

Comment: I saved it properly then program ran properly(Thanks). But after any editing in class i have to save class again. I am just tired of saving this class file again and again. Note:- But program runs properly after i save the class file in developer console

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, you added the class in Execute Anonymous window but then tried to use it in an Apex class created in the org through setup.

If I understood what you meant correctly then this is to be expected. Code in execute anonymous does not persist beyond the execution, so the class disappears again as soon as the code finishes running. You must add the class [through setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_class.htm) or using an IDE and deploying or pushing to the org.

Comment: No no man, I created a Class directly in "Developer Console" (In developer org without IDE). It runs properly when I save the File. But the problem is after every change in class I need to save the class again to get the output (For example:- If i edited class by inserting a semi colon, again I have to save the class). This is annoying to keep saving class again n again. Any solution gys ?

Comment: What you are specifically doing is not clear. Could you edit the question and add some screenshot to show exactly what you do?